# Why is this question off-topic (and how do you get to know why a question is off topic after all)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, off-topic

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953984/replace-with-file-in-git-index-appears-disabled) on Stack Overflow and it was soon closed as off-topic. My question is why was it closed as off-topic? Especially since to my understanding, it's "a question about software tools commonly used by programmers". I understand it's just how SO works, so no whining from me, just being curious.

Additional bonus: I see there are many people here on Meta asking just that. Wouldn't it be convenient to place a small explanation when voting to close a question, visible to the OP? (Like the comments when editing)

Comment: Personally I see no reason to close this as off-topic, I've voted to reopen ("Too localized" I could kind-of understand).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Git is a programming tool. Eclipse is a programming tool. Programming tools are on-topic on Stack Overflow, I would consider the closure of this question as erroneous and I have voted to reopen.

And the users voting to close are free to (and encouraged) add a comment explaining why they voted to close, in cases where the stock close reason is not sufficient.

Comment: Isn't it better to notify the closers of their mistake? Because they'll just keep closing such questions unless someone will tell them otherwise.

Comment: I think that the REOPEN process has been "badly" defined because expiry time is too short for users as me that read a lot of old questions and answers. I'm not reading everytime StackOverflow new question's list. When I have a problem, I search and in 99% I find a question/answer older that 15 days. But never, I have the possibility to reopen a question closed because I read it too late. I think that to REOPEN process is too strict and give too much power to CLOSE.